# Socket.emit not sending or socket.on not receiving?

Tags: node.js, react-native, redux, socket.io, sequelize.js

I am building a mobile Chat app using Node.js, MySql, Sequelize, Socket, React Native and Redux.

I am trying to socket.emit the credential of the user to:
1) find or create the user and;
2) move to the next screen via the reducer.

I believe that either:

- `socket.emit('newUser', credentials) in ./store/index.js`

doesn't work, and / or both

- `socket.on('newUser', credentials => {...} in ./index.js`
- `socket.on('newUser', user => {...} in ./store/index.js`

do not work, because nothing is added to database an I do not move to next screen. Simply, nothing happen when I enter some credentials and hit the button.

I am fairly new to development and tried to understand where is the problem by using multiple console.log (removed from the code below), as I don't know how else to test it.
I have also checked all other threads on socket.emit and on how to test if socket is working for the past few days, but I am still stuck.

Below is my code.
1) why socket.emit doesn't send (or socket.on doesn't listen)?
2) How can I test if socket is working (both on client and server side).

Thank you!!

**./index.js**

```
const server = require('http');
server.createServer(function (req, res) {}).listen(3000);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

const { User, Conversation, Message } = require('./db').models;
const mobileSockets = {};

io.on('connection', socket => {

    socket.on('newUser', credentials => {
        const { name, password } = credentials;
        Promise.all([
            User.findOrCreate({
                where: {
                    name,
                    password
                }
            }),
            User.findAll()
        ])
        .then(([user, users]) => {
            mobileSockets[user[0].id] = socket.id;
            socket.emit('userCreated', { user: user[0], users });
            socket.broadcast.emit('newUser', user[0]);
        });
    });
});
```

**./App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={ store }>
        <RootStack />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

import LoginScreen from './components/Login';
import Users from './components/Users';
import Chat from './components/Chat';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: LoginScreen,
  Users: Users,
  Chat: Chat,
  }, {
  initialRouteName: 'Login',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerTitle: 'login to Chat!'
  }
});
```

**./components/Login.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { login } from '../store';

export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      password: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(type, value) {
    this.setState({ [type]: value });
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    login(this.state, this.props.navigation);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={ styles.container }>
        <Text style={ styles.text }>Enter your name and password:</Text>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={ value => this.handleChange('name', value) }
          returnKeyType='next'
          autoCapitalize='none'
          autoCorrect={ false }
          onSubmitEditing={ () => this.passwordInput.focus() }
          style={ styles.input }
        />
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={ value => this.handleChange('password', value)}
          secureTextEntry
          returnKeyType='go'
          autoCapitalize='none'
          style={ styles.input }
          ref={ input => this.passwordInput = input }
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={ this.handleSubmit }
          style={ styles.button }
        >
        <Text style={ styles.buttonText }>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'powderblue',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%'
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    width: '90%',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: 'black',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    color: '#000',
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 10
  },
  button: {
    width: '75%',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    borderRadius: 50,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 20,
    paddingVertical: 15
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  }
});
```

**./store/index.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import users, { gotUsers, gotNewUser } from './users';
import messages, { gotMessages, gotMessage } from './messages';
import user, { gotUser } from './user';

let navigate;

const reducers = combineReducers({ users, messages, user });

const store = createStore(reducers);

export default store;
export * from './users';
export * from './messages';

import socket from './socket';

});
socket.on('userCreated', response => {
    const { user, users } = response;
    store.dispatch(gotUser(user));
    store.dispatch(gotUsers(users));
    navigate('Users');
});
socket.on('newUser', user => {
    console.log('store/index.js has received a "newUser"');
    store.dispatch(gotNewUser(user));
});

export const login = (credentials, navigation) => {
    socket.emit('newUser', credentials);
    navigation = navigation.navigate;
};
```

**./store/socket.js**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
socket.connect();

export default socket;
```

Comment: bro, I don't know both redux and socket & I have to develop a chat app using them. I get my solution from your question thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a real solution to the problem, but I've managed to make it work by using express.

**./index.js**

```
// replaced the connection part of the code with this

const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

server.listen(3000);

// the rest of the code goes here
```